# Dynamically adding rows AdvancedDataGrid Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid being built dynamically from an html table. The html is provided by a server so my code has to work dynamically for different columns/rows.

I have the columns being built and they display properly, however when I get to adding the rows is where i have issues. the follow code snippet shows iterating over all of the columns and adding a value under each of those columns to an object (to make a complete row) and then adding that to the ArrayCollection that later gets set to the dataProvider for the AdvancedDataGrid

```
//create an item to work with
var chartItem:Object = new Object();
for( var j:int = 0; j < columnResult.length ; j++ ) 
{
    //this is the data that goes under the column (headerArray)
    var item:String = removeformat(removetd(columnResult[j]));
    //grab the header (this is which column the value will be added
    var head:String = headerArray[j];
    //set the value to header (pair)
    chartItem[head] = item;
}
//add the chartItem (row) to the main collection
arr.addItem(chartItem);
```

my issue is that when "head" has a value of 0, as in the column title is '0', the item is added at position [0] instead of at 0 as a string.

I looked up some examples and tried with:

chartItem.head   but that just assumes the column title is 'head' instead of grabbing the value of the head var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use numbers as an index in associative arrays.

Most of the time the index in an associative array is just a variable name of an Object. That's why you can access the data either with `obj["someKey"]` or `obj.someKey`. Of course you can use characters within your keys that are not allowed within variable names (like spaces, special symbols). However, you can access those only with brackets, not with dot (`obj["foo/bar"]` works, `obj.foo/bar` won't work). So, this is not recommended...

Well, back to your problem: I'd suggest you prefix all your column names with a character (e.g. use "_0"). Since you create the AdvancedDataGrid columns dynamically that shouldn't be a problem. You can explicityl set the `headerText` of those columns in order to still show "0" in the column header instead of "_0".

Comment: thanks that fixed the problem i had with the columns with a "0" header. however i seem to have another problem now... only some of the data seems to make it to the table. I don't have this issue where I have a simple table with only a few columns, however when i have a table with groupings (note that the groupings are displayed correctly and inspection of headerarray still shows it's getting the right column headers) some data is missing. i don't know where to start since stepping through the code it appears to be working right.

Comment: You should mark this question as answered and ask a new one for your other problem. Preferably with some working example code.